# automatically tag incoming and outgoing email based on date received/sent in outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, tags

I want to tag my email based on date received/sent so that I can review what I have done in each month. I have thinking of two sets of tags for this purpose, one set for month, another set for year. I can find in outlook "rules and alerts" that I have set a range of date to do so, but I need to set up a new rules every month, I wonder if this can automated, which means outlook will tag the email once it is received/sent based on month and year, without my intervention?

Answer (score 1):

The only reasonable way I can see is to create two custom properties: one for month and one for year. After that you can set them automatically using VBA macro in your rules that catch incoming/outgoing messages. And in the end you'll be able to create an Outlook folder view that will group your emails by these two properties: first by year and then by month.